# How to add a repeating Index or Rank column in Power Query (1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4 etc.)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a large table of data (the below image ([image: Data]) is a small subsection of the larger dataset) which I need to essentially add an index or rank column that repeats itself (1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4 etc. [image: Desired Data]). The reason for this is each two rows of data need to be associated with each other so I can properly pivot the attribute and value columns.

EDIT: Picture display

Answer (score 1):

Bring the data into PowerQuery with data .. from table/range...

Add column ... index column  ....

click select the index column

transform .. standard .. integer divide ... 2

Sample code if source data is in Table1

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"a", type text}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Integer-Divided Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 2), Int64.Type}})
in #"Integer-Divided Column"
```